# How do I find the associated name of a max of a sum in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

[image]

I have this schema here, and I need to find the **name** of the customer with the highest total amount for the orders. I have a SQL query here:

```
SELECT Name
FROM (SELECT Name, SUM(Amount) AS Total
      FROM customer JOIN orders ON cust_id = ID
      GROUP BY Name) AS Totals
WHERE Total = (SELECT MAX(Total)
                      FROM (SELECT Name, SUM(Amount) AS Total
                            FROM customer JOIN orders ON cust_id = ID
                            GROUP BY Name) AS X);
```

But this is very inefficient as it creates the same table twice. Is there any more efficient way to get the name?

Comment: your DBMS will probably see that there are 2 times the same query and optimize it for you

Comment: Not really if there can be more than one customer with the maximum total.

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.0 you can put the duplicate query in a CTE.

Comment: With MySQL 5.x you can use a VIEW.

Comment: @Barmar View does not guarantee anything, MySQL uses that just as "shortcut" to not repeat queries

Comment: @Berto99 Good point. It just makes the query easier to read, doesn't necessarily make it more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want customer with the greatest total mount, then you can just join, order by and limit:

```
select c.name
from customer c
inner join orders o on o.cust_id = c.id
group by c.id, c.name
order by sum(o.amount) desc 
limit 1
```

Note that this does not handle possible top  ties. For this, you need a little more code. Instead of ordering, you would typically filter with a `having` clause:

```
select c.name
from customer c
inner join orders o on o.cust_id = c.id
group by c.id, c.name
having sum(o.amount) = (
    select sum(o1.amount)
    from orders o1
    group by cust_id
    order by sum(o1.amount) desc
    limit 1
)
```

Finally: if you are running MySQL 8.0, this is simpler done with window function `rank()`:

```
select name
from (
    select c.name, rank() over(order by sum(o.amount) desc) rn
    from customer c
    inner join orders o on o.cust_id = c.id
    group by c.id, c.name
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: What if there are multiple customers that have the max?

Comment: @Barmar well he asked for the name of the customer (singular), so this is actually correct for the question

Comment: @Barmar: my edit covers that (I was typing while you were commenting...).

Comment: The version with `having` has the same problem as the original code, since it has to repeat the sum subquery.

Comment: @Barmar: yes - that's the way to go in MySQL 5.x... But it is still more straight-forward than OP original query, that had more levels of nesting.

Comment: why do we need to group by c.id and c.name, can't we choose one or the other?

Comment: @pastacompany: it handles the case when two customers have the same name. It is always a good idea to have the primary key in such `group by` clause.